# Average value using partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Let's say I have 4 particles with energy levels $0\,\rm{eV}$ , $1\,\rm{eV}$,and two particles with $3\,\rm{eV}$ energy levels. If I want to find the average value of energy I can say that
$$\bar{E}=\dfrac{(0+1+2\cdot3)\,\rm{eV}}{4}=1.75\,\rm{eV}$$

If I want to use the partition function to find the same average, I would say: $Z=e^{0}+e^{-\beta}+2e^{-3\beta}$  and to find average I can simply do:

$$\bar{E}=\dfrac{1}{Z}\sum_iE(i)e^{- \beta E(i)}=\dfrac{0+e^{-\beta}+3 \cdot2 e^{-2\beta}}{e^{0}+e^{-\beta}+2e^{-3\beta}}$$

which is not equal to the average that I found above.

This question shows that I am missing a key point about partition functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a key point about averages.

In your first case you have assumed all energies are equally probable.

In your second case you have assumed energies have a probability distribution $P(E)$ of $e^{-\beta E}/Z$.

In general the average energy is $\sum E\cdot P(E)$.